# Find the equation of the parabola with two points and a slope

Tags: calculus, derivatives

find the equation of parabola with given two points **B (2, 1)** and **C (4, 3)** and slope of the tangent line to the parabola matches the slope of the line goes through **A (0, 1.5)** and **B (2, 1)**.

i have calculated, that the slope for the line is -1/4. is it correct?
but i have no idea what the next step should be.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Slope of the tangent line at which point?

Comment: It seems like too much of a less information, firstly your parabola can be $(y-h)^2=4a(x-k)$ or it can be $(x-h)^2=4a(y-k)$

Comment: The slope you calculated is correct

Comment: there is nothing more said. just that it is the slope of a tangent line to the parabola.

Comment: so the derivative of the parabola equation (y=ax^2+bx+c) should be equal to -1/4? 2ax+b=-1/4 ? and what will be the x here?

Comment: So, your parabola is a vertical parabola? @Sarah , from equation you provided, still it'd be required to know where the tangent is drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this problem, you must derive a system of linear equations to solve for the three unknowns in your parabola $f(x),$ where $$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c. $$ We know $f(2)=1=4a+2b+c$, $f(4)=3=16a+4b+c$, and $f'(\text{B})=-\frac{1}{4}=4a+b$. Thus, the system $$\begin{cases}4a+2b+c=1\\ 16a+4b+c=3\\ 4a+b=-\frac{1}{4} \end{cases} $$ is established. I will leave it up to you to solve for $f(x).$

Answer (score 0):

$$y=ax^2+bx+c$$
use the two points to get
$$1=4a+2b+c$$
$$3=16a+4b+c$$

I think that the tangent point at point $B$ 
$$y'=2ax+b$$

$$-1/4=2*a*2+b$$

solve the simultaneous equation to get $a$, $b$, and $c$